# If 9 points are chosen from within the rectangle, explain why two of the points must be at most 18cm away from each other.

Tags: graphing-functions, area

I've been revising for an exam and the following question has stumped me. I thought it might involve pythagorean theorem but after trying it out it doesn't seem to...

"A rectangle has width 6 cm and height 12 cm. If 9 points are chosen
from within the rectangle, explain why two of the points must be at
most 18cm away from each other. [Hint: divide the rectangle into
squares of equal area.]"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you use the hint?

Comment: Yeah, I'm just not seeing it... I drew it out on graph paper to help visualise it but it just isn't clicking for me. I thought it may be something to do with a point in each corner of the rectangle (splitting it into two triangles and using pythagorean theorem) but that doesn't work.

Comment: Easier question: Can you explain why two of them must be $\le 10000 cm$ away from each other?

Comment: Hint: If you break the rectangle into $2$ squares of size $6\times 6$, then why must two of the points lie in the same square?  What is the furthest distance between any to points in the same square?

Comment: There isn't that much area within the rectangle?

Comment: What is the largest distance between two points in the rectangle? @AndrewGibbons

Comment: Does it have to follow a straight line?

Comment: @AndrewGibbons You are calculating a distance between 2 points, which is the length of the straight line connecting two points.

Comment: @JohnMa that's what I thought was meant... but I don't follow how two of them "must be at most 18cm away from each other".

Answer (score 1):

Divide the rectangle into squares $3cm\times 3 cm$, there are $2 \times 4 = 8$ of them. Two of the points will land in the same square, so the distance between them is at most the diagonal of the square $= 3\sqrt{2} cm = 4.24\ldots cm$.

Obs: Maybe the problem stated $\sqrt{18} cm$ ?

Comment: Having looked at the exam paper I suspect you may be correct that it is in fact the square root of 18cm and not just 18 cm... I just did a google search and the question seems to have been lifted from question 5(d) on this paper: http://www.etoncollege.com/userfiles/files/KS%20Maths%20A%202012%20pdf.pdf

Comment: The paper I'm using isn't the eton paper but the question is worded identically except for the square root part.

Comment: @Andrew Gibbons: Yes, indeed. Perhaps it was a clerical error. All right then, good  luck with your exam.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help... it really had me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Well I can find much more stronger bound $\sqrt{18}$. First one half $6\times 6$ must have at least 5 points. Then we divide this part on 4 equal parts $3\times 3$. Now in one of those there are 2 points. So they are apart at most $\sqrt{18}<18$.

Comment: Thanks again... I think I may have fallen foul to a misprint (see above).